# python stability of complex conditionals

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a piece of python code that can have several valid indentation patterns and its behavior changed by hitting accidentally hitting 'tab' and shifting 'elif X' on indentation to the right.

```
    if A:
        do_a()
        if B:
            do_b()
        elif C:
            do_c()
    elif X:
            do_x()
```

Is it advisable to always add 'else' cases with 'pass'?

Comment: Not necessarily, but it is advisable to only indent 4 spaces. `do_x()` should be vertically aligned with `do_a()`.

Comment: I have never seen any code that adds `else:pass` systematically.   I will only do this is there is some important comment I need to add to explain *why* I'm not doing anything.

Comment: @MattDMo. Running pre-commit after accidentally changing elif X: offset will 'fix' offset of do_x().

Answer (score 0):

It is not advisable to always add else cases with simply passing to compensate for tabbing. It jumbles code and reduces readability. As MattDMo has mentioned, you should align if and elif blocks that are on the same level.

```
if A:
    do_a()
    if B:
        do_b()
    elif C:
        do_c()
elif X:
    do_x()
```

Your code is functional as is, you should not add code without a good purpose rather than people mistakenly tabbing.